# EOL whilst scanning string literal - Python

Tags: python, python-3.3, eol

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to make code it so it will print out this ASCII art traffic light, here is the actual ASCII

```
  ##
                  _[]_
                 [____]
             .----'  '----.
         .===|    .==.    |===.
         \   |   /####\   |   /
         /   |   \####/   |   \
         '===|    `""`    |==='
         .===|    .==.    |===.
         \   |   /::::\   |   /
         /   |   \::::/   |   \
         '===|    `""`    |==='
         .===|    .==.    |===.
         \   |   /&&&&\   |   /
         /   |   \&&&&/   |   \
         '===|    `""`    |==='
      jgs    '--.______.--'
```

And the Code I'm trying to use is this

```
print ("##"),
print (" _[]_"),
print (".----'  '----."),
print (" .===|    .==.    |===."),
print (" \   |   /####\   |   /"),
print (" /   |   \####/   |   \\"),
print ("'===|    `""`    |==='"),
print (" .===|    .==.    |===."),
print ("\   |   /::::\   |   /"),
print (" /   |   \::::/   |   \"),
print ("'===|    `""`    |==='"),
print (".===|    .==.    |===."),
print (" \   |   /&&&&\   |   /"),
print (" /   |   \&&&&/   |   \"),
print (" '===|    `""`    |==='"),
print ("'--.______.--'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` characters, double them:

```
print (" /   |   \::::/   |   \"),
```

should be:

```
print(" /   |   \\::::/   |   \\")
```

You want to get rid of all the commas too.

Note that you can create a multiline string using triple quotes; make it a raw string (using `r''`) and you don't have to escape anything either:

```
print(r'''              _[]_
             [____]
         .----'  '----.
     .===|    .==.    |===.
     \   |   /####\   |   /
     /   |   \####/   |   \
     '===|    `""`    |==='
     .===|    .==.    |===.
     \   |   /::::\   |   /
     /   |   \::::/   |   \
     '===|    `""`    |==='
     .===|    .==.    |===.
     \   |   /&&&&\   |   /
     /   |   \&&&&/   |   \
     '===|    `""`    |==='
  jgs    '--.______.--'
''')
```

Comment: +1. I find it funny how the question's formatting shows the answer too :)

Comment: @Leonid: That edit is incorrect; the ``r'''\`` opening line doesn't work in a raw multiline string. A literal backslash will be included in the output.

Comment: I still don't understand it :/

Comment: @user2756717: What part don't you understand? You can fix your immediate problem by replacing all ``\`` characters with ``\\`` double slashes.

Comment: @user2756717: The detailed explanation can be found in the [string literal documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral).

Comment: What I don't understand, is what the 

print (r''' means, I know it solves the problem, but what does it actually mean?

Comment: @user2756717: Python has several different notations for defining a byte string literal (the value of a string in python source code). You can vary the quoting style (between single `'..'` and double `".."` quotes, to suit different contents), between a single quote character and triple quote characters (`".."` and `""".."""`, to accept literal newlines as part of the string value), and between regular and raw strings (`".."` and `r".."`).

Comment: @user2756717: I think you are wondering about the latter; *normal* strings accept a wide range of escape characters. `\n` means a newline, `\t` means a tab, `\xFF` means a byte value 255 in hex, etc. Each of those escapes starts with a backslash. The raw string literal form `r".."` *ignores* most of those escapes; the backslash character is interpreted as just a backslash in most cases. See the documentation I linked to for the exact details.

Comment: @user2756717: Your code specifically broke because you had backslashes at the end of the string, `\"` means 'escape the quote character' instead of 'here is the end of the string with backslash character, then the closing quote'.

Comment: Oh, so it tells Python to ignore the "\" basically?

Comment: Yes, for the most part; `\"` still allows for the quote to be included (but the backslash will be included *too*), and you cannot use a single backslash as the last character, but *on the whole* the backslash is included as a regular character, instead of seen as an escape sequence.